# What does alias which='alias | ... do?

Tags: linux, bash

I noticed this in CentOS out-of-the-box aliases

```
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

So, when you type `which`, actually pipe `alias` into `/usr/bin/which`, right? Seems a bit pointless

```
$> echo xxxxxxxxxx | /usr/bin/which echo
/usr/bin/echo
```

The pipe doesn't seem to do anything. What's supposed to be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias allows the `which` command to report on aliases in addition to binaries and shell functions.  For example, I have an alias for my ls command.  If I run `which ls` I get the following:

```
$ which ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    /usr/bin/ls
```

If I remove the alias for `which` by running `unalias which` then running `which ls` no longer shows the alias:

```
$ unalias which
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

The difference is because of the `--read-alias` option.  The man page for `which` describes it this way.

```
--read-alias, -i
    Read aliases from stdin, reporting matching ones on stdout. This is
    useful in combination with using an alias for which itself. For
    example
    alias which=´alias | which -i´.
```